# CMake add a library which is a group of other libraries

Tags: cmake

I have a core library which branches off into several other libraries. In CMakeLists.txt it looks a bit like this

```
ADD_LIBRARY (core ...)
ADD_LIBRARY (branch1 ...)
ADD_LIBRARY (branch2 ...)
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (branch1 core)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (branch2 core)
...
```

I have some executables which may depend on any or all of the branches. For those that depend on all the branches, instead of writing

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE (foo ...)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (foo branch1 branch2 ...)
```

I tried

```
ADD_LIBRARY (all-branches)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (all-branches branch1 branch2 ...)
```

then

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (foo all-branches)
```

This works but CMake spits out a warning.

```
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library all-branches without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
```

I understand the message, but it's not an error. What does CMake think is an acceptable way to build a meta-library like this?

Comment: I don't think CMake supports convenience libraries. One reason is Visual Studio does not have this concept. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Does_CMake_support_.22convenience.22_libraries.3F

Answer (score 14):

I added a new type of library, the INTERFACE library to the upcoming CMake 3.0.0 release. That is designed as the solution to this problem:

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries

```
add_library(all_branches INTERFACE)
target_link_libraries(all_branches INTERFACE branch1 branch2)

add_executable(myexe ...)
target_link_libraries(myexe all_branches)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. If I may comment, INTERFACE strikes me as a poor choice of keyword. It suggests other meanings. How about GROUP or CONTAINER or COLLECTION or something like that?

Comment: An INTERFACE library is more than just a collection, group or container and not semantically similar to such concepts. The name is suitable for what it does.

Answer (score 0):

In CMAKE the add_executable and add_library are very similar. They just tell to CMAKE that it should create a MAKE instruction for a library or executable based on the list of src files that you provide after the name of the library/executable and options (such as SHARED, etc).

What you can do is to add the names of your libs that you want to link in a name variable that you increase such as

```
SET(TARGET_LIBS ${TARGET_LIBS} myFirstLib)
SET(TARGET_LIBS ${TARGET_LIBS} myNextLib)
```

and then simply:

```
target_link_libraries(myExe  ${TARGET_LIBS})
```

In this way you can easily define *groups* of libraries that may be needed for different sub projects without creating a meta-lib.